# How to search through an Excel file in C#

Tags: c#, .net

The code I am using:

```
private void OpenExcelFile()
{

  Excel.Application exlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

  if (exlApp == null)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Excel app object could not be created");
  }
  else
  {

      exlFileSelector.FileName = @"*.xls";

      if (exlFileSelector.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
          Excel.Workbook wrkBook = exlApp.Workbooks.Open(exlFileSelector.FileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, true, true);
          Excel.Sheets sheetList = wrkBook.Sheets;

          Excel.Range search = exlApp.get_Range("A1", "C5");
          search.Find("FindMe", null, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, null, null); 
      }
  }
}
```

This is an answer that "codex" answered to a previous question asked in this forum. But when I copy it to my app the system doesn't recognize  `exlFileSelector.FileName`.
How can I fix it? What am I missing? 
I have been trying for some time to do a simple search within an Excel file but with no luck.
(I added the Excel reference needed for the project).
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found a code like this, i hope it little helps..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;


namespace testtesttestExcel
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()

{
InitializeComponent();
}


//Declare these two variables globally so you can access them from both
//Button1 and Button2.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objApp;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook objBook;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks objBooks;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets objSheets;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet objSheet;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range;


private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

try
{
// Instantiate Excel and start a new workbook.
objApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
objBooks = objApp.Workbooks;
objBook = objBooks.Add(Missing.Value);
objSheets = objBook.Worksheets;
objSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)objSheets.get_Item(1);

//Get the range where the starting cell has the address
//m_sStartingCell and its dimensions are m_iNumRows x m_iNumCols.
range = objSheet.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value);
range = range.get_Resize(5, 5);

//Create an array.
double[,] saRet = new double[5, 5];

//Fill the array.
for (long iRow = 0; iRow < 5; iRow++)
{
for (long iCol = 0; iCol < 5; iCol++)
{
//Put a counter in the cell.
saRet[iRow, iCol] = iRow * iCol * iCol;
}
}

//Set the range value to the array.
range.set_Value(Missing.Value, saRet);
objApp.Visible = true;
objApp.UserControl = true;

}

catch( Exception theException )
{
String errorMessage;
errorMessage = "Error: ";
errorMessage = String.Concat( errorMessage, theException.Message );
errorMessage = String.Concat( errorMessage, " Line: " );
errorMessage = String.Concat( errorMessage, theException.Source );

MessageBox.Show( errorMessage, "Error" );
}



Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range currentFind = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range firstFind = null;

string A = "16";

// You should specify all these parameters every time you call this method,
// since they can be overridden in the user interface.
currentFind = objSheet.Cells.Find(A, Type.Missing,
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole,
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false,
Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

while (currentFind != null)
{
// Keep track of the first range you find.
if (firstFind == null)
{
firstFind = currentFind;

//textBox1.Text = currentFind.get_Address(true, true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, false, Missing.Value);


}

// If you didn't move to a new range, you are done.
else if (currentFind.get_Address(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
== firstFind.get_Address(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, Type.Missing, Type.Missing))
{
break;
}

currentFind.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOl
(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
currentFind.Font.Bold = true;


currentFind = objSheet.Cells.FindNext(currentFind);
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although old question, but I will answer for future readers...exlFileSelector.FileName is just the file path to the Excel file you are attempting to read. Replace it with the complete file path to the Excel file you wish to read.