# Searching date string in file excel

Tags: c#, excel

I'm working with an excel file and I'm trying to find the position(address) of the cells with date value like "16/02/2015" as content. In order to do this with windows Forms application I use a datetimepicker. My code is as following:

```
// Firstly I want a string like 16/02/2015 inserted in the datetimepicker
string date = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString().Substring(0,10); 

        List<string> Testsdone = new List<string>();          

        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file_opened, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(4);


        Excel.Range currentFind = null;
        Excel.Range firstFind = null;


        Excel.Range tests = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("K13", "K2295");
                    currentFind = tests.Find(date);
        .....
```

I have exactly the same content "16/02/2015" written in my excel file, but the currectFind always shows null! I have no idea why the two "16/02/2015" are different. Anybody got an idea? thanks!

Comment: Have you tried by searching for an actual DateTime instead of converting it to string?

Comment: @Juan well no, because the values datetimepicker gives is date + time. In order to have only the date I have to convert it to string and make a substring of it. I don't know if there's a way to have only the date value, or I could search only the date part

Comment: You can do DateTime.Date to get just the date part of a DateTime struct

Comment: Can you show a sample of your excel file?

Comment: @Juan sorry but the value of DateTime.Date is like "16/02/2015 00:00:00". For you it's not like this?

Comment: @Rafet well I'd like to, but I don't know how to attach a file to my post. Anyway the format of the cell is text. If you need other information please let me know

Comment: Then I'd suggest you try `DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyy")` because you won't know what you'd get with substring.

Comment: @Rafet thx for the reply and that's a good idea. However the search is still failed. I shall figure out from other aspects. Thx again!

Answer (score 0):

Well after some investigation I found that the problem is caused by the Find function

```
currentFind = tests.Find(date);
```

which for unknown reason failed to find the date. From another post
[how to Search in excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727990/how-to-search-in-excel-file) I got this method, that I changed this into:

```
currentFind = xlworkSheet.Cells.Find(date, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,             Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole,   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false,Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

And it works. But I still have no idea why the Excel.Range.Find fails and Excel.workersheet.Cells.Find works