# Convert a string to an unknown type in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'd like to know how could I convert a string to an unknown data type which I extracted from an excel file. In my last post
[Searching date string in file excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968419/searching-date-string-in-file-excel?noredirect=1)  I wanted to search a date string like "16/02/2015" in an excel file since this date is explicitly written there. However I couldn't find it! Then I extracted this date object from the excel like

```
object d = Sheet.get_Range("K54", "K54").Value2;
```

I got my date string from a Datetimepicker like:

```
string date = Date.Value.ToShortDateString(); //16/02/2015
```

And I realized that I shall convert the date string to this type then I could find it in the excel. Somebody got any idea to do this? Thanks

Comment: Convoluted logic... not clear what you are asking... what is the Type of `object d` (break in debugger, inspect with Quick Watch)?

Comment: @DrKoch no idea! Breaking in debugger and moving my mouse onto it don't give me the information about its type

Comment: right click on `d` -> Quick Watch, third column: Type

Comment: @DrKoch Ok thx for the tip and I changed the "object" to "var" and found that the type is "dynamic {string}"

Comment: @jiangraf remember that dates in Excel are stored as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this:

```
object[,] cellValues;
Excel.Range worksheetCells = excelWorksheet.get_Range(firstCell, lastCell);
cellValues = worksheetCells.Value2 as object[,];
```

and values will be in cellValues array.